# Does Azure Artifacts support PyPi?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-server

I understand that Azure Artifacts supports Python, but does it support PyPi specifically? I am having trouble understanding what the scope is.

I use Azure DevOps Server 2020. I am not sure if that makes a difference versus Azure DevOps Services...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This old preview-announcement might explain the scope best. There might of course be more features implemented since that. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/python-package-pypi-support-for-azure-artifacts-now-in-preview/

You can search for those from the feature time line. That also mentions support for Azure DevOps Server - the preview feature was included in version 2019.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline

Documentation for Python packages here (Azure DevOps Server also mentioned as supported platform): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=azure-devops